# why the results are so different?

Tags: c++

I don't know why the similar code has a great difference? the first code outputs normally, but the second code outputs some unrecognizable characters. Who can explain it for me?

Thks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char a[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

    cout << a + 1 << endl;

    char b[5] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    cout << b+1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::cout sees a char*, a C-string.  Which must be zero terminated.  Your b[] is not, it isn't big enough.

Answer (score 11):

Both expressions `a+1` and `b+1` degrade into a `char*` which is then treated by `<<` as a NUL-terminated string, but only `a` is NUL-terminated. Accessing `b` as a NUL-terminated string causes undefined behavior, which in your case seems to be printing garbage after the first few characters. (Note that I originally said both were not NUL-terminated, but then I noticed that you had only 4 characters in the initializer for `a` but specified a size of 5. That means the 5th element would be zero-initialized, effectively NUL-terminating `a`.)

If you want to print them correctly without causing undefined behavior, make sure they are NUL-terminated:

```
int main(){

    char a[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }; // Works as-is, but not good form

    cout << a + 1 << endl;

    char b[6] = {'a','b','c','d','e', '\0'}; // Needed NUL-terminated, but still not the best way
    cout << b+1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or as eigenchris noted in a comment, you could rely on the compiler to NUL-terminate it for you by using a string constant instead:

```
char a[] = "ABCD";
char b[] = "abcde"; // Probably the best way to do this.
```

Comment: As an aside, you might prefer declaring strings with `char a[] = "ABCD";`, which will automatically null-terminate them.

Answer (score 3):

Since you send `char *` arguments to `cout`, like `a` or `b`, c style strings are expected. This means also the zero termination character is expected for each string. So the following will work:

```
char a[5] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '\0' };
cout << a + 1 << endl;

char b[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '\0'};
cout << b + 1 << endl;
```

The thing that this happens to `b` is that you overwrite zero character by defining all 5 characters. 0 should have been the sixth character.

Answer (score -1):

When you `cout << a+1`, the output will be "BCD", because the character after 'D' is a a nul (`\0`).
This is because you specified the array-size of 5, but only gave it 4 values.  The remaining, unspecified value will be set to 0.

When you `cout << b+1`, you'll get `"bcdeXXXX"`, which will continue until a nul is found.
(the `XXX` will be unpredictable characters based on whatever is in memory.)

This is because you specified the value of all 5 characters, and the memory beyond that is undefined.  It might be nuls, it might be random values left over from an earlier program.  There is no way to know for sure.  But `cout` will continue printing until it encounters a nul `\0`, or causes a segmentation/access violation by reading an inaccessible memory address.

That is why you get random garbage on the second output.